# Car not starting, battery reading 12.5V

Tags: battery

car wont start, had the same problem a couple months ago, but then it suddenly started.

Came out this morning, car didnt start, almost got it starting but the starter motor didnt get enough juice I guess. Got the volt meter out and the battery read 12.5v. Is that too low?

The car is around 8-9 yrs old and has never had a battery change. With this info, is it possible to say  that I need a new battery, or could it be something else?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

12.5 volts is good voltage for a battery, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's good. The first thing to do in this situation is to clean both ends of both battery cables and have your battery tested with a battery tester. Many Auto parts stores will test them for free.